# Need help with understanding a question concerning the power iteration method

Tags: linear-algebra, homework, iteration

I just need help understanding a question. I was given the question

> Use the power iteration method to estimate the spectral radius for (I - B A) given a tridiagonal coefficient matrix.

Although, I do not understand what the spectral radius part of this question means. I know how to compute, for the most part, a matrix using the power method. The ultimate goal is for me to be able to write Mathematica code implementing this.

Comment: Please consult your lecture notes or any other source on the notion of [spectal radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius). Until you have gotten familiar with the basics, this question is not really related to _Mathematica_.